# MSSQL: Create incremental row label per group

Tags: sql-server

In my table, I have a primary key and a date. What I'd like to achieve is to have an incremental label based on whether or not there is a break between the dates - column `Goal`.

Now, below is an example. The `break` column was calculated using LEAD function (I thought it might help).

I am able to solve it using T-SQL, but this would be last resort. Nothing I tried has worked so far. I am using MSSQL 2014.

```
PK  |   Date  | break | Goal |
-------------------------------
1   | 03/2017 |   0   |  1   |
1   | 04/2017 |   0   |  1   |
1   | 08/2017 |   1   |  2   |
1   | 09/2017 |   0   |  2   |
1   | 10/2017 |   0   |  2   |
1   | 02/2018 |   1   |  3   |
1   | 03/2018 |   0   |  3   |
```

Here is a code to reproduce this example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
    (
    ConsumerId INT,
    FullDate DATE,
    Goal INT
    )

INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2017-03-01',1)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2017-04-01',1)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2017-08-01',2)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2017-09-01',2)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2017-10-01',2)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2018-02-01',3)
INSERT INTO #test (ConsumerId, FullDate, Goal) VALUES (1,'2018-03-01',3)

SELECT      ConsumerId,
            FullDate,
            CASE WHEN (datediff(month,
                                isnull(
                                      LEAD (FullDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ConsumerId ORDER BY FullDate DESC),
                                      FullDate),
                                      FullDate) > 1) 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
            END AS break,
            Goal
FROM        #test
ORDER BY    FullDate ASC
```

**EDIT**

This is apparently a famous problem "Islands and gaps" as pointed out in the comments. And Google offers many solutions as well as other questions here at SO.

Comment: Are you looking for a query that would return the Goal column populated? Why using T-SQL would be the last resort?

Comment: Yes, I need to create the `Goal` column. Well the full table has 5M+ rows, so SQL will likely be faster.

Comment: Search "Gaps and Islands", eg http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I wish I knew the browser that can show the page properly, the code snippets are broken there.

Comment: Yep.  Itzik Ben-Gan does cover this in his books **"T-SQL Querying"** and the smaller **"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
WITH 
    cte_TestGap AS (
        SELECT 
            t.ConsumerId, t.FullDate,
            Gap = CASE 
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, t.FullDate, LAG(t.FullDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate)) = -1 
                        THEN 0 
                        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate) 
                    END 
        FROM
            #test t
        ),
    cte_SmearGap AS (
        SELECT 
            tg.ConsumerId, tg.FullDate,
            GV = MAX(tg.Gap) OVER (PARTITION BY tg.ConsumerId ORDER BY tg.FullDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM
            cte_TestGap tg
        )
SELECT 
    sg.ConsumerId, sg.FullDate,
    GroupValue = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sg.ConsumerId ORDER BY sg.GV)
FROM
    cte_SmearGap sg;
```

An explanation of the code an how it works...
The 1st query, in cte_TestGap, uses the LAG function along with ROW_NUMBER() function to mark the location of gap in the data. We can see that by breaking it out and looking at it's results...

```
WITH 
    cte_TestGap AS (
        SELECT 
            t.ConsumerId, t.FullDate,
            Gap = CASE 
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, t.FullDate, LAG(t.FullDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate)) = -1 
                        THEN 0 
                        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate) 
                    END 
        FROM
            #test t
        )
    SELECT * FROM cte_TestGap;
```

cte_TestGap results...

```
ConsumerId  FullDate   Gap
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           2017-03-01 1
1           2017-04-01 0
1           2017-08-01 3
1           2017-09-01 0
1           2017-10-01 0
1           2018-02-01 6
1           2018-03-01 0
```

At this point we want the 0 values to take on the value of the preceding non-0 values, allowing them to be grouped together. This is done in the 2nd query (cte_SmearGap) using the MAX function with a "[window frame](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1)". So if we look at the output of cte_SmearGap, we can see that...

```
WITH 
    cte_TestGap AS (
        SELECT 
            t.ConsumerId, t.FullDate,
            Gap = CASE 
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, t.FullDate, LAG(t.FullDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate)) = -1 
                        THEN 0 
                        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate) 
                    END 
        FROM
            #test t
        ),
    cte_SmearGap AS (
        SELECT 
            tg.ConsumerId, tg.FullDate,
            GV = MAX(tg.Gap) OVER (PARTITION BY tg.ConsumerId ORDER BY tg.FullDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM
            cte_TestGap tg
        )
    SELECT * FROM cte_SmearGap;
```

cte_SmearGap results...

```
ConsumerId  FullDate   GV
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           2017-03-01 1
1           2017-04-01 1
1           2017-08-01 3
1           2017-09-01 3
1           2017-10-01 3
1           2018-02-01 6
1           2018-03-01 6
```

At this point All of the rows are in distinct groups... but... We'd like to have our group numbers in a contiguous sequence (1,2,3) as opposed to (1,3,6).
Of course that's easy enough to fix using the DENSE_Rank() function, which is what's happening in the final select...

```
WITH 
    cte_TestGap AS (
        SELECT 
            t.ConsumerId, t.FullDate,
            Gap = CASE 
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, t.FullDate, LAG(t.FullDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate)) = -1 
                        THEN 0 
                        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ConsumerId ORDER BY t.FullDate) 
                    END 
        FROM
            #test t
        ),
    cte_SmearGap AS (
        SELECT 
            tg.ConsumerId, tg.FullDate,
            GV = MAX(tg.Gap) OVER (PARTITION BY tg.ConsumerId ORDER BY tg.FullDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM
            cte_TestGap tg
        )
SELECT 
    sg.ConsumerId, sg.FullDate,
    GroupValue = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sg.ConsumerId ORDER BY sg.GV)
FROM
    cte_SmearGap sg;
```

The end result...

```
ConsumerId  FullDate   GroupValue
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           2017-03-01 1
1           2017-04-01 1
1           2017-08-01 2
1           2017-09-01 2
1           2017-10-01 2
1           2018-02-01 3
1           2018-03-01 3
```

Comment: Some explanation and/or links to sources would be nice.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, I've updated my answer to include an explanation of how the code works and included a link to an Itzik Ben-Gan article that introduces the concept of "window frames". Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The comment from David Browne was actually extremely useful. If you google "Islands and Gaps", there are many variations of the solution. Below is the one I liked the most.

In the end, I needed the `Goal` column to be able to group the dates into MIN/MAX. This solution skips this step and directly creates the aggregated range.

Here is the [source](https://www.tangrainc.com/blog/2010/02/refactoring-ranges/).

```
SELECT      MIN(FullDate) AS range_start,
            MAX(FUllDate) AS range_end
FROM        (
            SELECT      FullDate,
                        DATEADD(MM, -1 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FullDate), FullDate) AS grp
            FROM        #test
            ) a
GROUP BY    a.grp
```

And the output:

```
range_start | range_end  |
--------------------------
2017-03-01  | 2017-04-01 |
2017-08-01  | 2017-10-01 |
2018-02-01  | 2018-03-01 |
```